# What would cause a domain user password change to take 30 minutes?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-7, password

A few times over the last few months, users have complained about extremely long password change wait times.  I can't find anything about this anywhere.  Is there a common cause for something like this?  We're using Windows 7 and Windows XP on a Windows 2003 domain.

Addenda: 
I have only one site with two domain controllers.  I'm not aware of any replication issues.  **dcdiag /test:replications** passed with flying colors and **repadmin /showrepl** shows successful replications.  If you have any other specific tests you'd like me to try, let me know.

**repadmin /syncall** & **repadmin /showrepl** show no errors and execute almost instantly.

Comment: Do you have many domain controller ? Did you check if this is not a replication problem ?

Comment: Try `repadmin /syncall`, wait 30 seconds then `repadmin /showrepl` and see if anything shows something other than successful.

Answer (score 2):

How many domain controllers do you have and how many sites do you have? If several sites what are the link speeds like?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check on your PDC emulator FSMO role holder for any issues.  Check performance counters on your domain controllers.  Run DCDiag /c /v >dcdiag.log and see if there are any failures.

Comment: No failures of any kind on the "dcdiag /c /v > dcdiag.log" test.

Answer (score 0):

On the Microsoft Website, there is a tool called AD Lockout, I think it is part of the Resource Toolkit.  While it is designed to show you which DC locked out an account,  it also displays the number of failed logins, and time of most recent failure.  You could change a password on a test user, then logout/login and look for which DC is failing the password.  This may give you a clue...

Answer (score 0):

Random thought, but what about clock time synchronization between machines?

Comment: Good thought, but everything is in sync.  The client machine that performed the password change and both DCs are right on.